# Iterating an array backward in C using an unsigned index

Tags: c, arrays, loops, unsigned

Is the following code, safe to iterate an array backward?

```
for (size_t s = array_size - 1; s != -1;  s--)
    array[s] = <do something>;
```

Note that I'm comparing `s`, which is `unsigned`, against `-1`;

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd write `for (size_t s = array_size; s--; ) { ... }`.

Comment: Sure, or simply `size_t s = array_size; while (s--) array[s] = <do something>;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is surprisingly tricky. If my reading of the C standard is correct, then your code is safe if `size_t` is at least as big as `int`. This is normally the case because `size_t` is usually implemented as something like `unsigned long int`.

In this case `-1` is converted to `size_t` (the type of `s`). `-1` can't be represented by an unsigned type, so we apply modulo arithmetic to bring it in range. This gives us `SIZE_MAX` (the largest possible value of type `size_t`). Similarly, decrementing `s` when it is `0` is done modulo `SIZE_MAX+1`, which also results in `SIZE_MAX`. Therefore your loop ends exactly where you want it to end, after processing the `s = 0` case.

On the other hand, if `size_t` were something like `unsigned short` (and `int` bigger than `short`), then `int` could represent all possible `size_t` values and `s` would be converted to `int`. In other words, the comparison would be done as `(int)SIZE_MAX != -1`, which would always return `false`, thus breaking your code. But I've never seen a system where this could happen.

---

You can avoid any potential problems by using `SIZE_MAX` (which is provided by `<stdint.h>`) instead of `-1`:

```
for (size_t s = array_size - 1; s != SIZE_MAX;  s--)
    ...
```

But my favorite solution is this:

```
for (size_t s = array_size; s--; )
    ...
```

Comment: Good point about the relative sizes. There have actually been implementations with 4-byte `int` with 2-byte `size_t` .

Comment: See also [What is the --> operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c)

Comment: In C89 there is no SIZE_MAX constant, what if I used `size_t SIZE_MAX = -1;` would that be correct?

Comment: @BiteBytes Yes, that would work. Or `#define SIZE_MAX ((size_t)-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `s` will never be `-1`, so your ending condition will never happen. `s` will go from 0 to `SIZE_MAX`, at which point your program will probably segfault from a memory access error. The better solution would be to start at the max size, and subtract one from everywhere you use it:

```
for (size_t s = array_size; s > 0; s--)
    array[s-1] = <do something>;
```

Or you can combine this functionality into the for loop's syntax:

```
for (size_t s = array_size; s--;)
    array[s] = <do something>;
```

Which will subtract one before going into the loop, but checks for `s == 0` before subtracting 1.

Comment: SIZE_MAX = -1 (at the binary level), isn't?

Comment: @BiteBytes I am not sure that for example for the sign and magnitude representation the operation s-- will give -1 when s is equal to 0.

Comment: It seems to work in C++11 (https://repl.it/KTS1/0) (albeit it's a bad practice) but I don't know how much of it is compiler specific vs standard defined.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Felix sayd **s will never be -1**, which is incorrect.

Comment: @BiteBytes-- it is correct that `size_t s` can never be -1: `s` is an `unsigned` value, after all, and `-1` is a `signed` integer value. But in the expression `s != -1`, the `-1` is converted to a `size_t` (so long as `size_t` is a wider type than an `int`, and this conversion is well-defined as a wrap-around value, so the comparison "works", but not exactly as might be expected. Where this answer goes wrong is with "so your ending condition will never happen."

Answer (score 0):

IMO in the iterations use large enough signed value. It ss easier to read by humans.